# Safe to store and reuse vector iterator values?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, stl, iterator

I am building a C++ program using graph. I am using vector of class. Problem is when I am inserting new object of class into vector previous values of iterator started pointing to some garbage values. My class is as follow:

```
class LinkedList
{
    public:
    int node;
    list <children> child;
    vector <vector <LinkedList>::iterator > pl; // it store the iteration values of parent of node
    vector <vector <LinkedList>::iterator > cl; // it store the iteration values of childof node
};
class children
{
    public:
    int dest;
    string label;
};
```

How much it is safe to store and reuse the iterator values?

Below function works as follows:

First it will find the parent and child of every node and store the iteration result respectively.

Secondly it will children of a graph (nodes with no furthur child nodes).

When it tries to insert child nodes into the graph, the iteration of other nodes become garbage.

```
void parentchildList(vector <LinkedList> &graph)//, vector <transclosure> &tc)
{
vector <int> childNode;

for(vector<LinkedList>::iterator ii = graph.begin(); ii != graph.end(); ii++)
{   

    for(vector<LinkedList>::iterator it = graph.begin(); it != graph.end(); it++)
    {
        for(list<children>::iterator li = it -> child.begin(); li != it -> child.end(); li++)
        {
            if(ii -> parent == li -> dest)
            {
                ii -> pl.push_back(it);
                it -> cl.push_back(ii);
            }
        }

    }
}


//Finding child nodes in a graph.
for(vector<LinkedList>::iterator ii = graph.begin(); ii != graph.end(); ii++)
{
    if(ii ->cl.size() != ii->child.size())          // finding child nodes and adding them to graph //linking child nodes 
    {
        bool flag = false;
        for(list<children>::iterator li = ii -> child.begin(); li != ii -> child.end(); li++)
        {
            flag = false;
            for(vector <vector <LinkedList>::iterator >::iterator itt = ii->cl.begin(); itt != ii->cl.end(); itt++)
            {   
                if((*itt)->parent == li->dest)
                    flag = true;
            }
            if(!flag)
                childNode.push_back(li->dest);
        }
    }
}


sort(childNode.begin(), childNode.end());
childNode.erase(unique(childNode.begin(), childNode.end()),childNode.end());

cout<<"Child Nodes are ";
for(vector<int>::iterator it=childNode.begin(); it!= childNode.end(); it++)
    cout<<*it<<" ";
cout<<endl;

for(vector<int>::iterator it=childNode.begin(); it!= childNode.end(); it++)
{
    LinkedList obj;
    obj.parent = *it;
    graph.push_back(obj);

    // Error happens here when I tried to insert a new obj into graph, all vaues of pl and cl becomes garbage.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***How much it is safe to store and reuse the iterator values?***

> std::vector::insert 
> Causes reallocation if the new size() is greater
>   than the old capacity(). 
> If the new size() is greater than capacity(),
>   ***all iterators and references are invalidated***. 
> Otherwise, only the
>   iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. 
> The
>   past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

[vector reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

You can safely assume that eventually the new size is going to be greater than the initial capacity.
 **Thus you are not using the right data structure.**

Your design is close to [adjacent lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). So use `std::list`, which [doesn't invalidate iterators or references upon insertion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert).

Btw [boost has an implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html) for adjacent lists..

Comment: But my requirement is I need to use either pointer or iterator in my code. I am facing the same problem when using pointers instead of iterators.

How can I use it. Can I reserve the memory in system before hand and how??

Comment: your code wont change much by switching from std::vector to std::list. you are fine.